# How to fix "You do not have permission to perform the 'ec2:DescribeSubnets' action" with AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess Policy

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Whenever I run `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment ...` the CLI returns success, but the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard shows error messages around `You do not have permission to perform the 'ec2:DescribeSubnets' action`.

I have created an Elastic Beanstalk instance, and given it a service role "Beanstalk-Dev-ServiceRole".  That role has three policies attached to it:

- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkService

(I've also tried just with AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess)

I've uploaded a zip package to S3 with the intended environment version (beanstalk-dev-server-2019-07-30--05-52-49), and verified it is there.

When I run `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name Beanstalk-Dev-Server --version-label beanstalk-dev-server-2019-07-30--05-52-49` the CLI reports success.  However when I look at the Beanstalk dashboard, all I see are two error messages:

- ERROR    Failed to deploy application.
- ERROR    Service:AmazonEC2, Message:You do not have permission to perform the 'ec2:DescribeSubnets' action.

I've seen various posts that say the DescribeSubnets action is part of the AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy.  It doesn't look like it is anymore, but the AWSElasticBeanstalkService has ec2:* so it should be covered there.  For kicks I've also tried adding a custom policy that explicitly allows ec2:DescribeSubnets to resource *, but all of my attempts keep coming back with that same error message.

Expecting the environment version to be updated with version specified in the CLI command, or at least an actionable error message.  Currently seeing an error message that I can't find any real actions on via search engines or docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for my case, the CLI commands were coming from CodeBuild, and the role assumed was that of the CodeBuild role, and not of the Beanstalk service or EC2 instance.

I did a deploy from the AWS console which got the general beanstalk infrastructure past the DescribeSubnets issue, and then tried another deploy from the CLI - this time it showed a more useful error message

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:User: arn:aws:sts::...:assumed-role/codebuild-.../AWSCodeBuild-... is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResource on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:...:stack/awseb-e-...-stack/...
```

That at least told me it was using the codebuild assumed role instead of the beanstalk assumed role like I expected it to.

Would be nice if AWS changed that DescribeSubnets error message to match most of its normal error messages around permissions.

Comment: You're right. The Beanstalk is not doing the action so adding ec2 permission to it will not make any difference. You need to update the IAM role of CodePipeline. You can find out which one it is by going to CodePipeline > Settings (side menu) and the Service role ARN will show up. Just add the missing permission to that role and you're golden.